# Errors while updating, installing applications or upgrading

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade, update-manager

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.2. Since a few days ago I am not able to successfully update or upgrade things. Whenever I execute an update or dist-upgrade command, I get error.

If I try to install new applications, I get an error saying the packages could not be authenticated.

(For example, I just removed and tried to install gnome-tweak-tool again.)

[image]

[image]

Executing `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` doesn't display anything as mentioned in some of the AskUbuntu post.

**EDIT:**

Entries of my sources.list file

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted
universe multiverse deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse deb
http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted
universe multiverse

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner deb-src
http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main
restricted universe multiverse

deb https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./

deb http://liveusb.info/multisystem/depot all main deb
[arch=amd64,i386] https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main universe deb
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security universe main deb
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates universe main
```

Comment: Can you add the output of "cat /etc/apt/sources.list" to your post please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i have solved the problem. I found out [this](https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/) website. I filled in the details it asked and then it generated the sources.list file contents for me. I am able to install and udpate software without much problems.

I still get errors for some DEP-11 Metadata icons repository where it says Permission denied. But, the 'packages cannot be authenticated problem' has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

You are running `xeinal` but using wrong repository source. actually it seems that your `sources.list` is set to use old-releases which does not contain `xenial` packages, etc.

Try running:

```
sudo sed -i s/old-releases/archive/ /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Also remove extra repositories from `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` if there is any.

Then run:

```
sudo apt update
```

---

If it did not work:

First to create a backup of `sources.list` file, Run:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list{,.bk}
```

Then run the bellow command to clear it:

```
    echo | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list
```

After that open it with an editor and root access:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then add the following code into it:

```
###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

Finally, save the file and update your sources:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Nope, it didn't work

Comment: @Logan updated, check if it's worked for you.